# Two-sided confidence interval for the sample for the mean length

Tags: probability, statistics, means, confidence-interval

A sample of $n \in \mathbb{N}$ screws is taken from a large batch of screws that are produced. The length of a bolt is approximated as normally distributed with variance $4$ and the lengths of the screws are distributed as independent and identical.

(a) $n = 10$ screws were taken and their length (in mm) was measured, with the following result: $$10 \ \ \ 8 \ \ \ 9 \ \ \ 10 \ \ \ 11 \ \ \ 11 \ \ \ 9 \ \ \ 12 \ \ \ 12 \ \ \ 8$$ Calculate the sample mean and determine a two-sided confidence interval for the above sample for the mean length of the confidence probability $0.95$. Also state the quantile used and its (approximate) value.

(b) How many screws had to be tested at least, thus a confidence interval for the mean length with a confidence level of $0.95$ has at most the length $2$ or length 1? Explain.

$$$$

I have done the following :

(a) The sample mean is equal to \begin{equation*}\overline{x}_{10}=\frac{1}{10}\left (10+8+9 + 10 + 11 + 11 + 9 + 12 + 12 +8\right )=\frac{1}{10}\cdot 100=10\end{equation*}

For the two-sided confidence interval do we use the formula \begin{equation*}\left [M(x)-\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}q_{1-\frac{a}{2}},M(x)+\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}q_{1-\frac{a}{2}}\right ] \end{equation*} where $M(x)$ is the mean, i.e. $M(x)=10$ and $\sigma=\sqrt{4}=2$ ? The value of $q$ is related to the confidence level, right?

Comment: I have a sample variance of $2$. The calculation is $Var(x)=\frac1{10}\cdot \sum\limits_{i=1}^{10} (x_i-10)^2$

Comment: So do we not use the given variance $4$ ? Do we calculate that by ourselves by the data of the sample? @callculus42

Comment: Oh, I haven't recognized this information. You are right to use the given variance. And yes, the value of q is related to the confindence level and the normal distribution.

Comment: Dowe have that $q_{1-a/2}=1.96$ ? So we get then \begin{align*}\left [M(x)-\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}q_{1-\frac{a}{2}},M(x)+\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}q_{1-\frac{a}{2}}\right ] &=\left [10-\frac{2}{\sqrt{10}}\cdot 1.96,\ 10+\frac{2}{\sqrt{10}}\cdot 1.96\right ] \\& \approx \left [8.760387,\ 11.23961\right ] \end{align*} Is that correct ? @callculus42

Comment: Perfect, Mrs Star.

Comment: Great!! At (b) do we have to find $n$ such that the length of the interval is at most $2$ or $1$ ? The length of the interval is $$M(x)+\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}q_{1-\frac{a}{2}}-(M(x)-\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}q_{1-\frac{a}{2}})=M(x)+\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}q_{1-\frac{a}{2}}-M(x)+\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}q_{1-\frac{a}{2}}=2\cdot \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}q_{1-\frac{a}{2}}$$ or not? So we want to find such that $2\cdot \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}q_{1-\frac{a}{2}}\leq 2$ or $2\cdot \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}q_{1-\frac{a}{2}}=1$ ? Or have I undnerstood that wrong? @callculus42

Comment: No it is right. So in the first case with length $2$ it is $\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}q_{1-\frac{a}{2}}\leq 1$. Don't omit the inequality sign.

Comment: So in the first case we have $2\cdot \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}q_{1-\frac{a}{2}}\leq 2 \Rightarrow \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}q_{1-\frac{a}{2}}\leq 1$ and in the second case we have $2\cdot \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}q_{1-\frac{a}{2}}\leq 1$ ? We have $\sigma=2$ and $q_{1-\frac{a}{2}}=1.96$ as before, right? @callculus42

Comment: Perfect, Mary..

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!! :-) @callculus42

Comment: Nice that you could manage the exercise almost by yourself.

Comment: I have posted also a similiar question. Could you maybe have a look at it ? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4370024/two-sided-confidence-interval-with-a-confidence-level-of-0-9 @callculus42